# create database and connect native android app

Tags: android, sql, database, rest, heroku

I'm making a native android app with has some user data that I want to be stored in a database.
I'm planning to use Heroku to host it. The app should be able to retrieve it and overwrite it.
Right now, I am very confused as to how to start working on it.

There are three parts:

1)writing the actual database: right now I'm using SQlite database browser. I have created a simple table database. I have no clue how to deploy this to Heroku...

2)writing a REST API to communicate with android app on device: I gather that I should also deploy this to Heroku?

3)Connecting with the device: ??? I have no clue how this works... do I write a REST API in my native android app too?

Very confused! thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow these steps as per my knowledge:

1. The database that you create should be for the device(the one that you have created using `sqlitebrowser`.
2. Create a separate database at the server side and create an api that'll perform CRUD operations using an `xml` or `json` file to reflect the data in it in the database at server
3. whatever operations you perform you can do them in the local database and later after checking the internet connection write the edited valueds in `xml` or `json` format and send it to your server where it'll be synced with the server database.

Comment: Hi, so I create two databases, one integrated with my android code(so that would be in java), and one to push to my server on heroku (maybe also in java?). 

Then I only need one API or do I also need 2 APIs for both my server and device?

Comment: also, how would I use an xml file? isn't that just formatting? what do you mean "whatever operations in the local browser and then checking the internet connection": (thats for my phone right) what if I want it sort of done transparently? thanks!!

Comment: @sam you will need only one API at the server. For syncing use this api to send your copy of local DB(in xml/json format and only the data that you need to sync) at the server for processing which you do at the server.
1) n "whatever operations in the local browser"(by mistake i said browser. Its "database") i mean do changes locally on device.
2) "After checking internet connection" i meant do the operations required for syncing only after checking if your device has working internet connection.

Comment: thanks phoenix! I will try that sometime. However, I'm currently having problems deploying an app to heroku. :(   if you know anything about heroku, please check out my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246779/heroku-your-account-is-unverified-and-cannot-create-the-requested-app-please

Comment: @sam if you found my answer satisfying among other(i don't see any other) then you could always mark it as accepted ;)